# Idea how to prove the following complex numbers inequality

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

I want to prove that for $z\in \mathbb{C}$:

$$12\operatorname{Re} z- 5\operatorname{Im}z\leq 13 |z|$$ 
I try to prove it using $|\operatorname{Re}z|\leq |z|$ and $|\operatorname{Im}z|\leq |z|$, but hasn't work. And idea would be great.

Comment: set $$z=x+iy$$ and try to prove your inequality

Comment: I must admit that it is still unclear to me on what criteria questions are closed as "off-topic because of missing context..." or not. Here OP at least mentions what estimates he used (of course it would have been better to show the actual calculation). But there are many other questions e.g. about some "interesting" inequalities which show no attempt at all and are not closed.

Answer (score 4):

Set $w = 12 + 5i$, then 
$$
  12 \operatorname{Re} z -  5 \operatorname{Im} z 
 = \operatorname{Re}(wz) \le \lvert wz \rvert = \lvert w \rvert \lvert z \rvert = 13 \lvert z \rvert \, .
$$

Alternatively, use the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality):
$$
  12 x - 5 y \le \lvert 12 x \rvert + \lvert 5 y \vert
 \le \sqrt{12^2 + 5^2 } \cdot \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = 13 |z| \, .
$$

Answer (score 1):

setting $$z=x+iy$$ then we have to prove
$$12x-5y\le 13\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$ squaring this and after some algebra we get $$0\le (5x+12y)^2$$ which is true.